# Bindgen does not cross-compile to ARM due to stdint.h

Tags: c, rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I have a C library that I wrap into a Rust crate using `bindgen`. My `build.rs` is straightforward and very similar to [this](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/tutorial-3.html). The C library is using `pthreads` internally.

In principle, my cross-compilation works for pure Rust targets, but in combination with the `bindgen` C-library it stops working. Compiling for my host platform (`x86_64`) works fine, but when I try to cross-compile for `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` (Raspberry Pi Zero)*, I get the following errors:

```
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least8_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:44:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least16_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:45:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least32_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:46:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least64_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:49:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least8_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:50:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least16_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:51:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least32_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:52:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least64_t'
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdio.h:39:10: fatal error: 'bits/types/__fpos_t.h' file not found
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least8_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:44:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least16_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:45:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least32_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:46:9: error: unknown type name '__int_least64_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:49:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least8_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:50:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least16_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:51:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least32_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:52:9: error: unknown type name '__uint_least64_t', err: true
/home/andreas/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/stdio.h:39:10: fatal error: 'bits/types/__fpos_t.h' file not found, err: true
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to generate bindings: ()', src/libcore/result.rs:1188:5
```

I used it with the built-in tools of Rust and with the normal `clang` + `gcc` toolchain on my system and compiles fine natively. Now I switched to [raspi-toolchain](https://github.com/Pro/raspi-toolchain) and set the `CPATH` to the header files I have downloaded from my Raspberry Pi Zero, but the problem persists (it only changes from errors based on `pthread.h` to `stdint.h`).

In `build.rs`, I first run `cmake` and then I do the following:

```rust
let dst = cmake::Config::new("../")
        //...
        .build();
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
```

How can I proceed from here?

The same happens for the armv7 target.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too. I got bindgen to look in the right spot by adding:

```
.clang_arg("--target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
```

to the bindgen builder.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add more headers from the Raspi part:

```
/usr/include
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys
```